# Multiplicative Functions

Tags: number-theory

Prove that if $f$ and $g$ are multiplicative, then so is

$$F(n) = \sum_{d|n} f(d)g\left(\frac nd\right) $$

I have an understanding of how to prove it for a single function, but 2 functions and a summation added in confused me.

Comment: Well, the first thing to do is state what it means for $F$ to be multiplicative.

Comment: For it to be multiplicative

$$F(ab) = F(a)F(b)$$

Comment: Hint: If $m,n$ are relatively prime, then the set of divisors of $mn$ is equal to the set of products $d_1d_2$ where $d_1\mid m$ and $d_2\mid n$. This lets you "split" the sum.

Comment: Right, what does it mean for it to be multiplicative?

Comment: So if I split the sum by summing over $d_1|m$ and $d_2|n$ I can get to $F(m)F(n)$. Let me work it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the outline of the proof.

Let $m,n$ be relatively prime. Then 
$$F(mn)=\sum_{d\mid mn} f(d)g\left(\frac{mn}{d}\right)$$

$$= \sum_{d_1\mid m,\,d_2\mid n} f(d_1d_2)g\left(\frac{mn}{d_1d_2}\right)$$
$$=\sum_{d_1\mid m}\sum_{d_2\mid n} f(d_1)g\left(\frac{m}{d_1}\right)f(d_2)g\left(\frac{n}{d_2}\right) $$
$$=\left(\sum_{d_1\mid m}f(d_1)g\left(\frac{m}{d_1}\right)\right)\left(\sum_{d_2\mid n}f(d_2)g\left(\frac{n}{d_2}\right)\right)$$
$$=F(m)F(n)$$

There is stuff that needs to be filled in here. Specifically, if $m,n$ are relatively prime, then any divisor $d$ of $mn$ can be written in exactly one way as a $d_1d_2$ where $d_1\mid m$ and $d_2\mid n$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $m$ and $n$ be coprime numbers, for ant divisor $d$ of $mn$, we can factor $d$ uniquely into the form of $d=d_1d_2$, where $d_1\mid m$ and $d_2\mid n$, this just follows from the factorization theorem. Conversely, this is also true. Then 
\begin{eqnarray*}
F(mn)&=&\sum_{d\mid mn} f(d) g(mn/d)\\
&=&\sum_{d_1\mid m}\sum_{d_2\mid n} f(d_1d_2) g(m/d_1 \cdot n/d_2)\\
&=&\sum_{d_1\mid m}\sum_{d_2\mid n} f(d_1)f(d_2) g(m/d_1 )g(n/d_2)\\
&=&F(m)F(n)
\end{eqnarray*}